# JS Получить все значения value в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

Подскажите, пожалуйста как собрать все значения value в массив,для последующей работы с ним. Вот пробую написать

```js
var mixedPictureSelect = document.getElementById("mixedPictureSelect"),
  mixedPictures = mixedPictureSelect.children,
  mixedPicturesLen = mixedPictures.length;

var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < mixedPicturesLen; i++) {
  var val = mixedPictures[i].value;
  arr = arr.push(val);
}

console.log("arr = " + arr);
```

```html
<select name="mixedSelect" id="mixedPictureSelect" class="mix_workPlace__select">
  <option value="picture1" data-id="0">text1</option>
  <option value="picture2" data-id="1">text2</option>
  <option value="picture3" data-id="2">text3</option>
  <option value="picture4" data-id="3">text4</option>
</select>
```

не понимаю почему push в моем случаии е формирует новый массив из значений value option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) - меняет массив, у которого вызывается, и возвращает новую длину.

Поэтому в данном случае не надо было присваивать результат выполнения той же переменной.

```js
var mixedPictureSelect = document.getElementById("mixedPictureSelect"),
  mixedPictures = mixedPictureSelect.children,
  mixedPicturesLen = mixedPictures.length;

var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < mixedPicturesLen; i++) {
  var val = mixedPictures[i].value;
  arr.push(val);
}

console.log("arr = " + arr);
```

```html
<select name="mixedSelect" id="mixedPictureSelect" class="mix_workPlace__select">
  <option value="picture1" data-id="0">text1</option>
  <option value="picture2" data-id="1">text2</option>
  <option value="picture3" data-id="2">text3</option>
  <option value="picture4" data-id="3">text4</option>
</select>
```

---

Новый массив возвращает метод [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). Если его использовать вместо `.push` в текущем коде, то все заработает.

```js
var mixedPictureSelect = document.getElementById("mixedPictureSelect"),
  mixedPictures = mixedPictureSelect.children,
  mixedPicturesLen = mixedPictures.length;

var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < mixedPicturesLen; i++) {
  var val = mixedPictures[i].value;
  arr = arr.concat(val);
}

console.log("arr = " + arr);
```

```html
<select name="mixedSelect" id="mixedPictureSelect" class="mix_workPlace__select">
  <option value="picture1" data-id="0">text1</option>
  <option value="picture2" data-id="1">text2</option>
  <option value="picture3" data-id="2">text3</option>
  <option value="picture4" data-id="3">text4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/*arr =*/ arr.push(val); // returns new length
```